# Problem: nothing provides libjsoncpp.so.1()(64bit) needed by llvm6-6.0.1-43.25.sles12.x86_64 while installing edb-as12-server in SLES12

Tags: sles, edb

Trying to install EDB -PPAS 12 version in SLES12 , But it throws such library errors:

````
node1:/etc/zypp/repos.d # zypper install edb-as12-server
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libjsoncpp.so.1()(64bit) needed by llvm6-6.0.1-43.25.sles12.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install edb-as12-server-12.6.7-1.sles12.x86_64
 Solution 2: break llvm6-6.0.1-43.25.sles12.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): c1```


Is it safe to go to solution2?
````

Comment: It would be safer to actually find the dependency as ignoring dependencies would give you headaches later on.

Comment: Please suggest me the best way to find the dependency and resolving it as i am new to SLES

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with SuSE (which I'm assuming you're using).  Also, this question would probably be more suitable for ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in the comments, it's safer to avoid breaking dependencies. You did not tell us which service pack of SLES 12 you're using. Nevertheless, starting with SLES 12 SP1, the package you're searching for is available in the PackageHub repository.

Check out: https://packagehub.suse.com/packages/jsoncpp/

Since you mentioned that you're new to SUSE, this page might help you to enable that repository on your system: https://packagehub.suse.com/how-to-use/